# How to read VTI files and convert them into pictures in Python

Tags: python

I have some .vti files and want to batch read it in python.
And in this script:

```
import vtk
reader = vtk.vtkXMLImageDataReader()
reader.SetFileName("test.vti")
reader.Update()
image = reader.GetOutput()

writer = vtk.vtkJPEGWriter()
writer.SetInputData(image)
writer.SetFileName("test.jpg")
writer.Write()
```

I have meet this problem：2022-08-03 08:48:42.504 (   0.293s) [                ]      vtkJPEGWriter.cxx:228   WARN| vtkJPEGWriter (0000023C41876F70): JPEGWriter only supports unsigned char input

Anyone could help me ?